# Using G / g Standard Patterns for or LocalDateTime values

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, nodatime

I'm trying to parse LocalDateTime values using Noda Time LocalDateTimePattern.Parse() method. I'm in the US. The following call to  Parse() fails:

```
var localDateTimePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.Create("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var parseResult = localDateTimePattern.Parse("4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM");
```

This fails as well

```
var localDateTimePattern = LocalDateTimePattern.Create("g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var parseResult = localDateTimePattern.Parse("4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM");
```

What am I doing wrong?  My idea was to be able to parse DateTime string presented in a standard to a current culture format.

Using BCL like the following works:

```
DateTime dateTime;
var parseResult = DateTime.Parse("4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM");
```

(Related formatting question was asked here: http://goo.gl/Q8DYTB)

Comment: You're using the invariant culture, so it shouldn't matter that you're in the US. Offhand, it seems like what you have should work (though I'm not near a computer at the moment, so I can't try it myself). Is the error message you receive from the parser at all useful? Failing that, have you tried _formatting_ a known `LocalDateTime` using that pattern to see what format you end up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Passing `null` to a `IFormatProvider`, or a `CultureInfo` parameter, will use the *current* culture, not the invariant culture.  It's equivalent to passing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.
- For methods like `DateTime.Parse` or `ToString` that have overloads that omit the format provider, `null` is assumed - which again, maps to the current culture, *not the invariant culture*.
- In the invariant culture, the `"G"` format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.  You *must* pass two digits (using a leading zero if necessary) in all fields (except year, which is 4 of course), and you *must* pass time in 24 hour format.  AM/PM indicators are not allowed.
- If you wish to use `"G"` with the current culture, then pass `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, or if you know the culture you want, then pass that specific culture.
- The `"g"` format is the same as `"G"`, except it doesn't include seconds.
- Noda Time is identical to the normal types in all of the above, *except* that it doesn't allow for `null` to be passed.  I believe this is intentional, to avoid this sort of confusion.

So, your methods are failing because you are passing only one-digit for a month, and passing 12-hour time format, but the invariant culture doesn't allow that.  Try instead:

```
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.Create("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var parseResult = pattern.Parse("04/10/2014 15:03:11");
```

Or perhaps:

```
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.Create("G", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var parseResult = pattern.Parse("4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM");
```

Or if your current culture is not in that format, then use a specific culture:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.Create("G", culture);
var parseResult = pattern.Parse("4/10/2014 3:03:11 PM");
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, you always help me. I'll try when I come to work  tomorrow.

Comment: Matt, could you answer one more question? See it in a main post update. I can achieve the same thing using DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateTimeOffsetISO8601).ToString(); but prefer to do it "Noda Time style".  Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a new question rather than a refinement to this question.  Please keep StackOverflow usage guidelines in mind.  Please move your edit to a new question and I'll respond there.  The end result of question and answer(s) should be valuable to others searching for this information in the future.  Thanks.